Travel to UK for tourism as a US citizen with a Class 1 Misdemeanor suspended jail sentence of 12 months (probation only and fines) ending 2011
This question may have been asked many times before but I am going to ask again still. I am a US citizen with a Class 1 Misdemeanor in the US (for profane language over phone/voice message) for which I was convicted in 2010 and sentence received was a fine $1000.00, 12 months supervised probation and suspended jail sentence for the same period which ended in 2011. UK Immigration rules clearly state that entry must be refused over a custodial sentence between 12 months - 4 years but entry will not be refused if it was a non-custodial sentence after which more than 12 months have passed. I guess my sentence was non-custodial since there was no jail time (suspended jail sentence for 12 months). I hope I am safe to travel since my sentence ended in 2011 so please let me know what you think. I was looking at section 9.4.4. for Visitors here https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal
(This question is different from other questions asked because I categorically received a "suspended incarceration sentence of 12 months" as opposed to not getting any imprisonment/jail time/incarceration)
Research: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/grounds-for-refusal-criminality/grounds-for-refusal-criminality-accessible Suspended sentences:
These count as a ‘non-custodial offence or other out of court disposal recorded on a person’s criminal record’, unless they are ‘activated’. This means the person has reoffended or otherwise breached the conditions of that sentence. Where that happens, you must consider the original suspended sentence length, the circumstances that led to its activation, and the length of time in custody the person was required to serve following activation.

"I guess my sentence was non-custodial since there was no jail time" - you may find that your sentence was actually custodial.  You were sentenced to jail time, so it was a custodial sentence, but that custody was suspended.  I don't know if that's how it would be interpreted by UK immigration though.

Thank you for the inputs. I have edited my question. After looking at whats custodial versus non-custodial it appears my sentence may be custodial so that makes travel very "iffy" and I may have to just take a chance, be honest at UK immig, and leave it to the immig officer to decide my fate. Thats risky because I cannot travel there without making travel reservations or bookings either since the immig officer may question that part as well.

However, under Immigration Rules for visitors I do fit this category (b) since more than 10 years have passed: V 3.4 An application (except for an application for an extension of stay as a
visitor) will be refused if the applicant has been convicted of a criminal
offence for which they have been sentenced to a period of imprisonment of:
(a) at least 4 years; or
(b) between 12 months and 4 years, unless at least 10 years have
passed since the end of the sentence; or
(c) less than 12 months, unless at least 5 years has passed since the end
of the sentence

@Midavalo - Research on Suspended Sentences: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/grounds-for-refusal-criminality/grounds-for-refusal-criminality-accessible Suspended sentences:
These count as a ‘non-custodial offence or other out of court disposal recorded on a person’s criminal record’, unless they are ‘activated’. This means the person has reoffended or otherwise breached the conditions of that sentence.

@midavalo - the same website Absolute and conditional discharges
---conditional discharge – the person is released with conditions imposed for a set period (1 to 3 years): no further action is taken unless they commit a further offence within that period in which case they can be re-sentenced for the original offence as well as the new one. Absolute and conditional discharges are considered as non-custodial sentences or out-of-court disposals, recorded on a person’s criminal record.
